# how to get this equation of the expectation of absolute square of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm reading a paper which uses a lemma saying
$$
\mathbb{E}\lbrace |X|^2 \rbrace = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \Pr(|X| \ge \frac{h}{2})h d h
$$
but I have checked a lot of books, nobody telling this equation, anybody know how to derive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $E|X|^{2}=\int_0^{\infty} P(|X|^{2} \geq t) dt$. Make the substitution $h=2\sqrt t$.

Comment: WOw, that is right!